# Controlar número de acessos do usuário em Windows Forms

Tags: c#

Estou criando uma aplicação em Windows Forms e gostaria de controlar para que os usuários façam login em uma única estação que esteja executando a aplicação.
Em uma versão anterior, a minha solução era manter uma pasta compartilhada em um servidor e quando o usuário entrava na aplicação eu abria um arquivo txt para edição com o nome do usuário. 
Desta forma, quando o mesmo fosse abrir de outra estação, quando a aplicação tentava gravar esse arquivo gerava um erro.
Gostaria de alterar esse formato pois hoje nem todas as estações possuem acesso a mesma pasta compartilhada.

Comment: Já pensou em controlar em uma tabela no banco de dados?

Comment: Pensei desta forma: Criaria um registro quando o usuário fizesse o acesso e excluiria quando fosse fechar o sistema. Mas se o sistema encerrar inesperadamente, o registro ficaria criado e bloquearia o usuário de acessar novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma coluna em seu banco de dados do tipo `boolean` para quando ele estiver logado.

Adicionando a tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela_usuarios ADD 'logado' boolean;
```

Para colocar a boolean como `true` ao abrir o form, você pode utilizar o evento `Form_Load()` desta forma:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checklogado())
    {
        string comando = "UPDATE tabela_usuarios SET logado=1 WHERE usuario=@Usuario";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, connection); //connection é a string da conexão.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario); //usuario seria o nome de usuário da pessoa logada.
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Você já está logado em outra máquina!", "Erro");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

bool checklogado()
{
    string comando = "SELECT logado FROM tabela_usuarios WHERE usuario=@Usuario";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario);
    bool returno = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    return retorno;
}
```

Para colocar a boolean como `false` ao fechar o form, você pode utilizar o evento `Form_FormClosing()` desta forma:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    string comando = "UPDATE tabela_usuarios SET logado=0 WHERE usuario=@Usuario";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, connection); //connection é a string da conexão.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario); //usuario seria o nome de usuário da pessoa logada.
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Ainda precisa incluir uma verificação no evento Load e se o usuário já estiver locago, apresenta uma mensagem e não deixa logar. Indico também armazenar data/hora e maquina que o usuário efetou o login.

Comment: @RodolphoSa obrigado pela dica, editei minha resposta.

Comment: O problema é de ocorrer alguma falha e o sistema encerrar de forma indevida. Então o usuário não conseguirá entrar novamente!

Comment: Você pode fazer uma coluna para o tempo logado na seção e um evento em que o usuário é automaticamente deslogado quando ultrapassa 3 horas.